# Undefefined is not an object - PROBLEM with this.State (FIREBASE/REACT NATIVE)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Been spending over 4 hours solving this problem with no luck. I recently began learning how to code with react and javascript to create an app that allows users to add their favourite locations to a list.

I was able to connect to firestore and return the data to a state, but for some reason, I can't access it in "render()" and "return()". My console logs the values such as longitude and latitude but when I access the state through  it doesn't work. Here is the code, see below for the photos

```
state = {
        regionSet: false,
      }

componentDidMount() {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords
          const region = {
            ...this.state.region,
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.008,
            longitudeDelta: 0.008,
          }
          this.setState({ region, regionSet: true })
        })

        userData = async () => {
          const user = auth().currentUser;
          var userRef = firestore().collection('favoritelist').doc(user.uid).collection(user.uid);
          
          const markers = [];
              await firestore().collection('favoritelist').doc(user.uid).collection(user.uid).get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {
                  querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                  markers.push(doc.data());
                });});
                this.setState({markers});
                console.log(this.state.markers)
                console.log(this.state.markers[0].lat) 
                
          };
          
        userData()
      }
```

```
render() {

      const { markers } = this.state
      const user = auth().currentUser;
      const mapRegion = {latitude:  37.782822, longitude: -122.4067605}

        return (
          
          <View>
            {console.log(markers)}
            <Text>
                {this.state.markers[0].lat}
            </Text>
          </View>
```

[console logs the data/state perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K54UI.png)

[state doesn't work in a text and return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl1sq.png)

[image: Content of the state this.state.marker]

Thank you for reading and helping out if possible :)

Comment: because the `markers[0].lat` doesn't exist the first time you are rendering your view. Check if `markers[0].lat` exists and then conditionally render it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what you mean (still pretty new haha). It can console.log (marker) in render() but can't when it is markers[0].lat which I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

So basically what's happening is your React component is getting the data from fire-store but the component is already rendered and the easiest way to fix is to change `markers[0].lat` to `markers[0]?.lat`. This will show data once its available. Hope this fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for the help Callmeizaz, however, it's still showing the same error - undefined is not an object

Comment: can you refer to this thread :https://stackoverflow.com/q/61537120/15774176 is it helpful?